# Spring Data Cassandra custom insert query failing at '.' in String

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I have written a custom save query so that I can add a configurable TTL on each item.  Here is my repo:

```
@Repository
public interface MyCassandraRepository extends
                                         TypedIdCassandraRepository<MyCassandraItem, UUID> {

    @Query("insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + CQL_UUID + ", " + CQL_PLAN + ") values (?0, ?1) using ttl ?2")
    MyCassandraItem customSaveWithTtl(UUID uuid, String plan, Integer ttl);
}
```

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_users.plans (
   user_id uuid,
   plan text,
   PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
) ;
```

However, when I try to add an entry where the plan String contains a full stop/period (eg. `eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.hsdyu7832uwhjjdsjkdsew2389dhj`), I get the following error:

`org.springframework.cassandra.support.exception.CassandraQuerySyntaxException: line 1:110 mismatched input 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9' expecting ')' (...plan) values ('c7a8fd65-8ef5-420e-b02e-898fe248bbf3', ''[eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9]....); nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:110 mismatched input 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9' expecting ')' (...plan) values ('c7a8fd65-8ef5-420e-b02e-898fe248bbf3', ''[eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9]....)`

Trying to add it manually using CQLSH, I also get an error with the '.':

`SyntaxException: line 1:826 no viable alternative at input '.' (... "plan") VALUES (c7a8fd65-8ef5-420e-b02e-898fe248bbf3, [eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9].hsdyu7832uwhjjdsjkdse...)`

Can anyone see how I can get it to add the whole String and not just stop at the '.'?

Answer (score 0):

You may try using **PreparedStatement**

```
String originalPlan = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.hsdyu7832uwhjjdsjkdsew2389dhj";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = cqlTemplate.getSession().prepare("insert into plans (user_id, plan) values (?, ? )");
Statement insertStatement = preparedStatement.bind(UUIDs.timeBased(), originalPlan );
cqlTemplate.execute(insertStatement);
```